# Authentication error because of session timeout on login page of WSO2IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Whenever I leave the login page for more than one minute, and then try to login, i am getting the following error:

Authentication error!
Something went wrong during the authentication process. Please try signing in again.

And the logs are saying the following:

TID: [-1234] [] [2019-09-26 11:15:46,065] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.handler.request.impl.DefaultRequestCoordinator} -  Context does not exist. Probably due to invalidated cache

I've already enabled the Session Persistence on identity.xml , even tried changing the values of the

```
<TimeConfig>
    <SessionIdleTimeout>15</SessionIdleTimeout>
    <RememberMeTimeout>20160</RememberMeTimeout>
</TimeConfig>
```

Are there any files that can over write this option? Right now, the session timeout is after a minute and I can't figure out where to modify this.

Answer (score 1):

There are two kinds of sessions in the WSO2 IS. The session during the authentication flow and the session created after the user gets authenticated successfully. The first one is identified by the "sessionDataKey" which is passed along with the other parameters in the flow like username, password. The second kind of session is identified with the "commonauthId" cookie.

"Idle Session Timeout" is talking about the second type, how long the user's SSO session will be kept. When we consider about your issue, it is not related to this "Idle Session Timeout". There we have to consider the authentication context.

So, we have to focus on "SessionDataPersist" in the identity.xml. Make sure it is enabled and temporary is set to true. Otherwise, temporary data on the authentication flow will not be persisted into the DB and delayed requests could be failing if the cached data got cleared soon.

```
<SessionDataPersist>
    <Enable>true</Enable>
    <Temporary>true</Temporary>
```

If we have enabled temporary session data persistent correctly, it will keep the authentication context information in the DB until the DataCleanUp task cleans up the old entries from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

For the super tenant, the "SessionIdleTimeout" is read from the identity.xml in the first server startup only. For other tenants, it is read from the config file while creating the tenant. Later the configuration is stored in the database and changes to the config file will not get applied.

Therefore, you have to update the "Idle Session Time Out" value under the resident identity provider from the Management console.

[image]

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately, I have done that as well :( Same configs are in there which is 15 mins and 20160 . ANy other ideas?